# How to query “not” value on different fields?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have this mongo database:

```
{ "name" : "A", "action" : "walk" }
{ "name" : "B", "play" : "run_walk" }
{ "name" : "C", "action" : "run_walk" }
{ "name" : "D", "play" : "walk" }
{ "name" : "E", "move" : "walk" }
{ "name" : "F", "move" : "run_walk" }
```

Now,I need filter out the item which "play" or "action" or "move" value is "run_walk" and get this result:

```
{ "name" : "A", "action" : "walk" }
{ "name" : "D", "play" : "walk" }
{ "name" : "E", "move" : "walk" }
```

The mongo version is 2.6.X.
Some reason make I can't update mongo version to higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [`$nor`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/):

```
db.collection.find({
  "$nor": [
    { "play": "run_walk" },
    { "action": "run_walk" },
    { "move": "run_walk" }
  ]
})
```

Or simply "starting with run": {

```
db.crap.find({
  "$nor": [
    { "play": /^run/ },
    { "action": /^run/ },
    { "move": /^run/ }
  ]
})
```

Or in PHP parlance

```
find([
  '$nor' => [
    [ 'play' => 'run_walk' ],
    [ 'action' => 'run_walk' ],
    [ 'move' => 'run_walk' ]
  ]
])
```

And the same "starts with"

```
find([
  '$nor' => [
    [ 'play' => [ '$regex' => '^run' ] ],
    [ 'action' => [ '$regex' => '^run' ] ],
    [ 'move' => [ '$regex' => '^run' ] ]
  ]
])
```

That's basically a [`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) and [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) condition combined, looking for where any of the specified conditions "do not match".

Nothing version dependent about that as these basic query operators have been around since the initial release.

Comment: If I don't need item is start with "run_",how to do this via aggregate?Thank you.

Comment: @Lamyee Nothing to do with aggregate. "Starts with" is just a `$regex`. See above